# Does stationary increments and self similarity imply Hölder?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $X(t)$ be a real valued continuous stochastic process. Suppose that $X(t)-X(s)=(t-s)^a X(1)$ in distribution for some $a\in (0,1)$.

If $X$ has infinitely many moments then Kolmogorov continuity criterion gives that $X$ is $\alpha$ Hölder continuous for all $\alpha \in (0,(pa-1)/p)$. Sending $p$ to infinity gives that $X$ is Hölder for all $\alpha<a$.

What about $X$ with no moments?

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but I show that it is possible to obtain such a conclusion assuming adequate weak type bounds on $X(1)$ (which do not require the existence of any moments). We work on $[0, 1]$ for convenience, the global a.s. Holder continuity follows from the local version without an issue.

Fix an $\alpha < a$. By a density argument in the first step, and a union bound in the second, for each $K > 0$, we obtain

$$\mathbb P(\{\text{the } \alpha \text{ Hölder norm of } X > K \})$$

$$\leq \mathbb P\left(\left\{\left|X \left(\frac{j}{n}\right) - X\left(\frac{k}{n} \right)\right| \geq K\left(\frac{j-k}{n}\right)^\alpha \text{ for some }  n \in \mathbb N, j > k \in \mathbb Z \right\}\right)$$

$$\leq \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \sum_{0 \leq k < j \leq n} \mathbb P\left( X \left(\frac{j-k}{n}\right) \geq K\left(\frac{j-k}{n}\right)^\alpha \right) $$

$$= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{0 \leq k < j \leq n} \mathbb P(X(1) \geq K(j-k)^{\alpha - a}n^{a - \alpha} ).$$

Thus we see that if $X_1$ satisfies enough weak type bounds, then we can conclude the probability above tends to $0$ as $K \to \infty$, and hence deduce $\alpha$-Holder continuity of $X$. I am not sure how to further reduce the above into a tractable checkable condition though. It appears that the above sum is dominated by terms that are close, e.g. those with $j - k \leq \frac{n}{2}$, so some combinatorics might be able to help obtain a cleaner condition.

*Comments: The bounds used are very coarse, however I suspect that some kind of weak type bound is a necessary condition for the result to hold.*

Comment: Consider the contribution of $(n,j,k)$ with $k\le n/3$ and $j\ge2n/3$. This contribution with be $\infty$ for any $K$ if $P(X(1)>x)>0$ for all real $x$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis That is discouraging.